# Ordering prints other than through iphoto

Tags: photos.app

I would like to order photo prints off of iphoto through phanfare because I like their quality of prints better than iphoto/kodak. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Phanfare have an iPhoto plugin

http://www.phanfare.com/apps.aspx#Iphoto

So you can export to them directly from iPhoto.